# Marking a view as "busy" in Cocoa

Tags: cocoa, nsview

I'm writing a Cocoa app, and I need to indicate to the user that a view is invalid and can't respond until a background job is completed.

Longer version:

A view in my app contains some data fetched from a server.  When the app determines that the data is invalid, it fetches fresh information and displays it.  Usually the update happens too quickly to see, but if server or network problems cause the background job to take more than a second or two, I need to make sure the user

1. Cannot interact with the view until the job is finished;
2. Can tell that the view is awaiting an update; and
3. Can continue to interact with other parts of the application until the job is finished.

1) is important because any operation initiated with the stale data will fail, and if the network or the server is slow, I don't want the user to waste his time with futile attempts to interact with that part of the application.  (It's fine if the user can still *see* the data.  That could conceivably be helpful, actually, but it isn't crucial.)

What is the standard way to do this in Cocoa?  For what it's worth, in the Eclipse framework I think I used the `showBusy` method on `ViewPart`.

If there isn't a standard way, does anyone have any suggestions for tackling it?  I haven't been using OS X very long, so I'm not even sure how an app is supposed to look and behave in this situtaion.  (The screenshots on this page looking promising, but it's iOS, not OS X:  http://cocoawithlove.com/2009/04/showing-message-over-iphone-keyboard.html)

Right now I'm working on replacing the whole view with an `NSProgressIndicator` and restoring the view after the task finishes, but removing the view means my app could end up in a funky state if something goes wrong.  Also, I'd like to be able to factor this functionality out into its own class or category(?) since I will have this issue with several different view classes in my application.  Ideally I'd like to end up with something as simple as Eclipse's view.showBusy(true)/view.showBusy(false).

Any and all help would be appreciated.
Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Why not just draw another view on top of the busy view? You could either have it display an image that means busy, or draw it as semitransparent, so it shades out the before-update version of the busy view.

Comment: That's what the iOS example I linked to shows.  The Apple user interface guidelines seem to recommend putting an asynchronous progress monitor nearby and letting the user figure out which view the progress monitor applies to, which seems inferior.  I still haven't figured out a convenient solution.  In this case, I ducked the problem by having the client subscribe to changes in the data instead of polling the validity of the data, so the client is never in a state where it knows it has stale data.  It assumes its data is valid until an update arrives from the server.